# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 has stopped working (solutions on Stack Overflow not working)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8.1

Error message:

> A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

This was the error message I got when I tried to launch [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012) on my Windows 8.1 system. There is no other information to act upon other than this, which is rather the same as "We don't know what's wrong. We will tell you if we know (but I don't think we do)". It was actually working before it just decided to stop.

The last configuration I made before it began to show this error was that I selected the option to load the last solution whenever I launch Visual Studio, and this was done in the options dialog. I don't think that could have caused Visual Studio to suddenly crash. The previous error message included something that had to with a change in configuration.

I have checked that ActivityLog.xml file in.

There were basically four errors:

1. Construction of frame content failed. Frame identifier: ST:0:0:{74946827-37a0-11d2-a273-00c04f8ef4ff} Frame caption: Exception details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell5.LoadPackageWithContext(Guid& packageGuid, Int32 reason, Guid& context) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
2. SetSite failed for package [Visual Studio Component Model Host Package]
3. End package load [Visual Studio Component Model Host Package]
4. End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage]

I have searched on Stack Overflow, [Bing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing) and Google. The solutions I got from there didn't work. Some had to do with registry settings, deleting keys, etc. I even disabled all the extensions from the registry. There was a time it was showing another message that "Object reference was not set to ...".

I don't know what to do. The only solution I have not tried is the one that I should download the updates. Update 4 is about 2 GB. That will take me, at least a week to download. Is there anything I can do?

PS: I tried to uninstall it. It does absolutely nothing. From the Control Panel, there's only the option to change. Clicking it seems to do something but nothing appears. I tried running from the set up from the .iso file. It shows nothing, too. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably nothing we can help you with here, my view is that you need to reinstall VS. If you cannot uninstall or repair it then you should contact Microsoft.

Comment: I can't even reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix this problem by installing latest version of of .NET Framework. May be helpful for others as well.